# How can I get the count of total duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, database, group-by

Suppose, I have a table "**Employee**"

```
|  id  | Name  |
----------------
|   1  |  AAA  |
----------------
|   1  |  AAA  |
----------------
|   2  |   BBB |
----------------
|   2  |  BBB  |
----------------
|   2  |  BBB  |
----------------
```

I want to count the duplicate rows so result will be 5 ( in total of 2 and 3)

The query I tried is:-

```
select count(id)
from Employee
group by id
having count(id) > 1
```

which give the output as expected:-

```
  | 2 |
   -----
   | 3 |
   -----
```

How can I achieve the total , I mean 5

Comment: SUM the Count(id)

Comment: Which dbms?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to wrap it in another query:

```
SELECT SUM(counts) 
FROM (
select count(id) counts
from Employee
group by id
having count(id) > 1) inner_query
```

Edit:

a more complicated way would be to use `group by`, the `sum window function` & `distinct` in the same statement to avoid the inner sub query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER () count_duplicates
FROM Employee
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted generic solution ,no particular db. So I executed the first one and it gave error:- Incorrect syntax near ')'  it is for last line

Comment: what database are you using? the statements above definitely valid in postgresql & mssql

Comment: @BlackCat, and the first statement is also valid on mysql.

Comment: it is sql server

Comment: sorry, it works now! I forgot to add "inner_query", thanks

Comment: here are the sample fiddles showing that the 1st statement works: [MS SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/47501/1), [Postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47501/1), [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e64e84/1)